# How can I get a similar amount of views/likes/faves etc as I get on my 500px account? I get NOWHERE near anything remotely similar on Flickr

Tags: flickr, 500px, social-media

I have **exactly** the same photos on my 500px and Flickr accounts *(through an IFTTT setup, saves me time)*. However, my 500px account has ≈ 2 000 views and my Flickr account has somewhere around 10 *(keep in mind that these are the total views of all my photos put together)*!

What I have discovered that 500px has a 'New' photos section where you can see the most recent photos posted on the site (9gag, Imgur, Reddit and others have the same), and Flickr doesn't *(at least, I haven't found it)*. I suspect that this is at least one part of the problem. Another one is that Flickr seems centred around people that have huge amounts of followers, and those people, I suspect, created their accounts back in the day when Flickr was just a couple of thousand people. I find it really difficult to get any traction at all on Flickr.

If you have any tips, recommendations or advice, please don't hesitate to put it here, rather than just deleting this thread as irrelevant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about creating photographs, it is about social media.

Comment: I think this question should stay. The Help section says nothing about questions only relating to 'creating photographs'. It *does* make provision for 'photography in society'. These days photography is for many people inextricably intertwined with social media. It is for many people the only reason they take photographs, and it is a vital aspect of marketing for photography businesses. The question is about social media, yes, but specifically as it pertains to photography.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct about the new photos section on 500px.  I was very surprised when I posted my first photos on 500px and immediately started getting likes.  Flickr has nothing like that.  To get more views in Flickr you can post your photos into various groups.  Some are better than others.  You just have to search for ones that seem to have regular activity.  Another thing to do is like, comment and follow photos that you like.  Many people will do the same for you.  Make sure you do it with recently posted photos because there any many inactive accounts on Flickr.